# Triggering "work item created" across Azure DevOps projects using Azure Logic Apps

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-devops-extensions

We need to do some "post-processing" on work items created and/or updated in Azure DevOps.

We are trying to see if Azure Logic Apps can do this for us, and luckily Azure Logic Apps contains a step designed for this - "DevOps - When a work item is created".

However - I am required to specify the "source project" in Azure DevOps:

[image]

But we need to be have the flow triggered *across* our project pool.

The only was we can see is to deploy an Azure Logic App for each project, which is undesirable for us for at variety of reasons - a major one is the maintenance nightmare it will create for us.

So - can we make a trigger in Azure DevOps that will be hit when a work item is created/updated ... across projects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> can we make a trigger in Azure DevOps that will be hit when a work item is created/updated ... across projects?

Unfortunately, it seems that there is no related way to make a trigger across the projects.

Currently, `account name` and `project name` parameters are required. You could get more information about Azure Devops connector from this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/visualstudioteamservices/#triggers).

> a major one is the maintenance nightmare it will create for us.

My workaround is that you could use program way(API or ARM template) to create the Azure Logic Apps.

You also could give your [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/287593-logic-apps) to the Azure Logic App team.